# Gradle test fails with error

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

I see next in my output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> superClassName is empty!
```

I appreciate if someone knows how to fix it.

I've already took a look to the http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1682. But any solution didn't help

Created Gist with more information:
https://gist.github.com/emartynov/c88194c702b77f42a7c0

Here is stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
    at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:49
)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskEx
ecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.jav
a:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStor
e.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskA
rtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.j
ava:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExec
uter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.j
ava:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.j
ava:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:275)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:30)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildEx
ecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactState
CacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuild
Executer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.
java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.
java:25)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:20
1)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:17
4)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: superClassName is empty!
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.getSuperTestClassFile(AbstractT
estFrameworkDetector.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitDetector.processTestClass(JUnitDetector.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.processSuperClass(AbstractTestF
rameworkDetector.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitDetector.processTestClass(JUnitDetector.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.processSuperClass(AbstractTestF
rameworkDetector.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitDetector.processTestClass(JUnitDetector.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.processTestClass(AbstractTestFr
ameworkDetector.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner$1.visitClassFile(DefaultTestClassScan
ner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner$ClassFileVisitor.visitFile(DefaultTes
tClassScanner.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:171)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:171)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:171)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:124)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner.detectionScan(DefaultTestClassScanner
.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner.run(DefaultTestClassScanner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.TestMainAction.run(TestMainAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestExecuter.execute(DefaultTestExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:448)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTas
kFactory.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTas
kFactory.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:499)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
java:64)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: could you post a bit more information? build file, what are you trying to build. dependencies, etc...

Comment: I've created Gist with our build script: https://gist.github.com/emartynov/c88194c702b77f42a7c0

Comment: Can you run your tests with the `-s` command line flag so we can narrow down the actual test class that is failing? Please post the produced stack trace.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing an @Test annotation in one of the tests. Are you using JUnit?

I don't think this is a gradle problem.

Comment: We are using junit. How does junit recognize tests without @Test annotation?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko added stacktrace

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Sounds like [GRADLE-1682](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1682). Turning off class file scanning should solve the problem:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class" // whatever Ant pattern matches your test class files
}
```

Comment: It works! Interesting if I could understand which class is causing issue

Comment: You can run Gradle with `gradle test --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true`, set an exception breakpoint, and connect a debugger on port 5005. Probably want the Gradle sources for this (clone project from GitHub or download zipball).

Comment: In my case it was caused by a utility class I had added to the src/test/java tree that was used by tests but was not itself a test. Solution worked perfectly as is since my class name did not have a "Test" suffix.

Comment: Please go to https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1682 and **vote** for this issue to be fixed.  It's almost 4 years old now!

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, this did not work for me for a Spring Boot project.