# Gradle not running TestNG tests, even with test.useTestNG()

Tags: gradle, testng

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.4"

    compile 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0.RC1'
    compile 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams-tck:1.0.0.RC1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '5.14.10'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

I have some implementation in Scala, and TestNG test in java. The test class actually does not contain any tests, but it's parent class does. Gradle seems to think there are no tests in the class.

```
Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:test (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:test
Skipping task ':test' as it is up-to-date (took 0.048 secs).
:test UP-TO-DATE
```

The test class is compiled in `build/classes/test`

Comment: Is the project hosted online?

Comment: Nope. I'll push it to github later.

Comment: @Opal Here it is: http://github.com/amorfis/gradle-testng-problem

Comment: I've correct output with gradle v2.2.1 for cmd `gradle clean test`. It seems that everything works fine.

Comment: Ok, when run with `-i` and `gradlew` it indeed skips `testClasses`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Add the following piece of code to *build.gradle*:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class" // whatever Ant pattern matches your test class files
}
```

**explanation:**

[Here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1682)'s the bug that causes problem you met. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814837/gradle-test-fails-with-error) the solution can be found. Don't forget to upvote all answers (I mean Peter's) ;)