# gradlew build is failing and giving me this, execution failed for task ':test'

Tags: java, gradle, testng, build.gradle, gradlew

I get this error

> execution failed for task ':test'

when I run **gradlew** build on the windows command line. Here is the link for my build scan https://scans.gradle.com/s/xectjoqky7vgo

I am trying to build `testng`. I do not know what this error means or how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814837/gradle-test-fails-with-error ?

Answer (score 0):

There are totally 3 failures

```
ParallelTestTest » verifyParallel[5](false, methods, 4) 0.330s
JarFileUtilsTest » generateTestJar  0.092s
DataProviderTest » parallelDataProviderSample
```

The `JarFileUtilsTest` failure was due to a missing xml file, which I have fixed as part of [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1725) pull request.

The other two failures, I am not aware of them failing all the time. I think it must be a sporadic failure.

I would request you to please try building the code once again (I have recently pushed in changes, which now makes TestNG need JDK8 instead of JDK7).

If you have any questions pertaining to TestNG, I would request you to please post on [TestNG-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/testng-users) google forum (for faster responses)